# The file name becomes "file.extension" whenever I upload a file to Onedrive using Integromat,

Tags: onedrive, make.com, integromat-apps

I'm trying to upload files (xlsx, docx, txt, pdf, img, etc.) saved in AWS cloud storage to OneDrive using the HTTP module (Get a file) in Integromat.
[image]

[image]

[image]

The contents of the file are uploaded to OneDrive without any corruption, but the file name is always "file.extension".

Any type of file brought the same result.

When I check the Operation of Integromat, I found that the file name is "file.extension" at the time of Output of Get a file.
[image]

I'm hoping you can point out what I'm doing wrong.

In addition, my colleague tried uploading a file with the same settings as above, and it was successfully uploaded with the correct file name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to grab the file name from the URL. (I don't have enough reputation to embed images as yet, so hopefully the links will work)

Steps involved might look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWq1B.png):

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw91W.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJusB.png)

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ago4b.png)

[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgBP1.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31924445)